# Google Checkout "Integration" section is missing. How to get it?

Tags: google-checkout

Apparently, if you create a Google Checkout account while creating your Google Android Market account, the Checkout account created is not a full-featured account, it is missing some sections.

Most notably, it is missing the "integration" section where you can get an API key to retrieve data automatically (needed, for example, for integration your own order processing system with Google Checkout).

My question is: is it possible to "upgrade" this "Android Market" Checkout account to a "normal" Checkout account, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

I've got an answer from Google support about this, and it is "Currently impossible". Here is what they said:

> The reason you see limited options in your Android related seller account
>   as opposed to a Classic Google Checkout account is because Android-only
>   merchants have a custom suite of features in their merchant account which
>   are only related to selling Apps on the market place. For example, while
>   your account has a merchant ID, the merchant Key is not be available for
>   now. We are currently working to enhance the tools available for merchants
>   to satisfy their requirements and hope to launch them soon, but we are
>   unable to comment on the exact timing of these launches.